RHEL9 subscription-manager cannot differentiate my original VM and the cloned VM
I have a registered RHEL9 VM and recently I have cloned a copy of it by restoring from the latest Veeam backup.
Then I changed the IP, gateway, also /etc/hosts file and regenerate /etc/machine-id file (also /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)
Then I executed subscription-manager unregister and subscription-manager clean on both VMs.
Also I have logined to web console of Redhat Hybrid Cloud Console to check there is no relevant systems registered.
Then I executed subscrption-manager register for both VMs, and expected that there will be two new entries on the Redhat Hybrid Cloud Console. However, I found that there is always only one entry, and seems the VMs were overwritting each other.
I have checked they have two different IPs, machine IDs, subscription-manager identity, still it seems when I try to register both, Redhat sees them as same system.
My question is what is the possible cause of this behaviour and how can I resolve it properly?
2025-01-02 Quick Update:
I found that both VMs ethnet has same MAC address somehow, would it be the cause? And is it normal for restored VM having same ethnet MAC address?


Have you try to delete the machines from RH site and try to register them again?

VMware should allow you to run a command on the clone and change the UID of the VHDD. This likely will make it different enough to identify as a new machine.
